# Keras model creation taking too much memory? [Kaggle]

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras, kaggle

I am building a model for semantic segmentation using kaggle and keras, and no matter what the model complexity is, just building the model itself is taking 15.1GB of GPU space and therefore I don't have any space to actually load any images even while using a generator. I always get an OOM error. Am I doing something wrong? Why does keras take 15GB just to create the model?
I have not yet compiled the model. This is right after just building the model [`model = Model(img_input, o)`]

[image: Sample Image 1]

[image: Sample Image 2]

Comment: whats your batch size and your input image shape?

Comment: @SohaibAnwaar this is before even setting up a batch size, this is right after creating the model.

Comment: By default TensorFlow allocates all GPU memory and manages it itself, so its not surprising to see that. 640x400 images are just too big for this GPU, you would have to downscale the images to a more reasonable size. For comparison ImageNet networks are trained on 224x224 image sizes.